# Building a ln function from scratch

Tags: logarithms

I need to write a natural logarithm with just limited available operations.
This is to be implemented as a function into a C program. The problem is, our product is security relevant so the source code has to be well documented and tested.
The testing process is why we are writing all code from scratch, as the C standard librarys are not well documented and writing our own tests for it that cover the whole library would take longer as just developing what we need our self.

Long story short:

I reviewed some opensource math librarys and just encoutnered for every `ln()`-function/method a quite big source with some nested dependencies to other even biger math-functions.

```
double log(double x)
{
    int e;
    double y, z;
    /* Test for domain */
    if( x <= 0.0 )
        return 0;

    /* separate mantissa from exponent */
    /* Note, frexp is used so that denormal numbers
     * will be handled properly.
     */
    x = frexp( x, &e );
    /* logarithm using log(x) = z + z**3 P(z)/Q(z),
     * where z = 2(x-1)/x+1)
     */

    if( (e > 2) || (e < -2) )
    {
        if( x < SQRTH )
        { /* 2( 2x-1 )/( 2x+1 ) */
            e -= 1;
            z = x - 0.5;
            y = 0.5 * z + 0.5;
        }   
        else
        { /*  2 (x-1)/(x+1)   */
            z = x - 0.5;
            z -= 0.5;
            y = 0.5 * x  + 0.5;
        }

        x = z / y;
        /* rational form */
        z = x*x;
        z = x * ( z * polevl( z, R, 2 ) / p1evl( z, S, 3 ) );
        y = e;
        z = z - y * 2.121944400546905827679e-4;
        z = z + x;
        z = z + e * 0.693359375;
        goto ldone;
    }
    /* logarithm using log(1+x) = x - .5x**2 + x**3 P(x)/Q(x) */

    if( x < SQRTH )
    {
        e -= 1;
        x = ldexp( x, 1 ) - 1.0; /*  2x - 1  */
    }   
    else
    {
        x = x - 1.0;
    }
    /* rational form */
    z = x*x;
    y = x * ( z * polevl( x, P, 5 ) / p1evl( x, Q, 5 ) );

    if( e )
        y = y - e * 2.121944400546905827679e-4;
    y = y - ldexp( z, -1 );   /*  y - 0.5 * z  */
    z = x + y;
    if( e )
        z = z + e * 0.693359375;

ldone:

    return( z );
}
```

This is code was allready hardened by me. But it is still depending on 4 other math functions (ldexp, polevl, p1evl and frexp) which I would have to implement my self aswell.

My math knowledge is allready overstrained with this code, so I couldn't verify even this is working correctly after I trimmed the code not mentioning implementing the additional implementations or the moment I had to document and jsutify the tests.

So why I'm asking here and not on StackOverflow:

I want to know, are there any easyer implementations or approximation procedures to determine the `ln` in a not that complex way, so I don't have to waste alot of resources for studying the maths behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For functions such as $\log$ from a standard library, I think it would be a mistake to reimplement them from scratch in the hope that your own implementation would be somehow "better". The standard implementations have been optimized for speed and accuracy for several decades, and it's unlikely that you can improve on it unless you are a highly specialized expert both in numerical analysis and the relevant hardware architecture.

That said, there are other libraries that are in some sense better, for example returning values that are guaranteed to be correctly rounded. For example, you might be interested in [crlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/)

---

Added: If you you want something simpler, and can live with a limited range of allowed input values, you can for example find a rational approximation of $\log x$. For example, computing the "(3,3) Padé approximation" of $\log x$ around $x=1$ gives:
$$
\log x \approx \frac{\frac{11}{60}(x-1)^3 + (x-1)^2 + (x-1)}{-\frac12 + \frac32 x + \frac 35(x-1)^2 + \frac1{20}(x-1)^3}
$$
giving reasonable accuracy, at least on the interval $[0.5, 4]$. Here is a graph of the two functions
[image]

and a graph of the quotient (showing relative accuracy)

[image]

Comment: I don't want to improve them, I can even live with a decent fallback in accuracee and performance isn't the problem either, but the problem is that our product gets approved for the market requires that each line of code (means also the functions invoked) is documented and tested. So the options are: build the math stuff from scratch and proof that the tests of them are justifing. or use the function of some one else and proof that its tests are justifing. So it woudl be more easy to write an own `log` as proofing some one else `log` works flawless, wouldn't it?

Comment: What kind of proofs are you looking for? Verifcation of correctness? Possible security flaws? Something else? The crlibm I liked to are verifyably correct.

Comment: so In other words, I'm looking for a simplification of a `log` while I can accept a certain inaccuracy

Comment: It's really hard to understand why your (most likely  inferior) implementation would be preferable. To me it seems like testing (in the computer science sense) of a *mathematical* function is to make sure that the function is accurate (and not crashing on any input). Again, the library I linked satisfies those criteria.

Comment: I'm not completly aware of the kind of proof. But it is the advice of my boss that we don't use external sources because that would simply waste resources in the testing phase. so even if I would get convinced that doesn't change the fact that I have to write it.

Comment: I'll have a look on it. and if you could include to your answer reasons about, why there is no way of simplifing this, I had at least an argument why this job shouldn't be done a) this way or b) by me.

Comment: If you want a simplified approach, it can probably be done. **But** you need a good specification: What kinds (ranges) of inputs should be acceptable? What accuracy is necessary? And so on. Otherwise, what would your own testing test?

Comment: the possible input would be real numbers from 0 to round about 2 going higher could happen but that could be waved away as the system would have other problems in that case to worry about.

Comment: Its worth noting that, for this kind of approach, the first step is it multiply/divide the input by e until its in the range 1/sqrt(e) < x < sqrt(e), and then use the formula. Each multiply/divide will add/subtract one from the output, which you will need to account for.

Answer (score 1):

I had to implement logarithms on rational numbers.

This is how I did it:

Occording to Wikipedia, there is the [Halley-Newton approximation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#High_precision)

[image: Halley-Newton Method]

which can be  used.

Using Newton's method, the iteration simplifies to (implementation), which has cubic convergence to ln(x).

```
// Using Newton's method, the iteration simplifies to (implementation) 
// which has cubic convergence to ln(x).
public static double ln(double x, double epsilon)
{
    double yn = x - 1.0d; // using the first term of the taylor series as initial-value
    double yn1 = yn;

    do
    {
        yn = yn1;
        yn1 = yn + 2 * (x - System.Math.Exp(yn)) / (x + System.Math.Exp(yn));
    } while (System.Math.Abs(yn - yn1) > epsilon);

    return yn1;
}
```

This is not C, but C#, but I'm sure anybody capable to program in C will be able to deduce the C-Code from that.

Forthermore, since

> logn(x) = ln(x)/ln(n).

You have therefore just implemented logN as well.

```
public static double log(double x, double n, double epsilon)
{
    return ln(x, epsilon) / ln(n, epsilon);
}
```

where epsilon (error) is the minimum precision.

Now as to speed, you're probably better of using the ln-cast-in-hardware, but as I said, I used this as a base to implement logarithms on a rational numbers class.

Arbitrary precision might be more important than speed, under certain circumstances.

Then, use the [logarithmic identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities) for rational numbers: 
logB(x/y) = logB(x) - logB(y)

Comment: This looks like a good way to improve on an initial estimate, that estimate coming from a Taylor series/Pade approximation.

Comment: @Eddy: The Taylor series approach is not efficient since the convergence is slow.
This is using Newton's method, which has cubic convergence to ln(x).

Comment: Yes, but what's your value of $y_0$? Im simply recommending, for example, $y_0=x-1$ using the first term of the taylor series.

Comment: @Eddy: Ah, well, then - a better start value - yes, why not.